# How to ask browser for geolocation on behalf of host domain?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, widget

I'm making a JavaScript widget which will be included on other people's websites. On customer's website, let's say `example.com`, the setup will be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mywidget.com"></script>
```

The widget has location-based functionality and makes a call to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()`

Unfortunately, the browser asks `https://cdn.mywidget.com wants to use your computer's location`. Allow or Block.

This is confusing to the user since they have no idea what `cdn.mywidget.com` is, because they are currently visiting `example.com`.

Is there a way to do `http://example.com wants to use your computer's location`?

Comment: Just do this server side? You can get their location via their IP adress?

Comment: That's not an option. At least not for my use-case.

Comment: Can you persuade your customers to host and include a tiny script that your widget can use?

Comment: also, is your widget in an iframe or is it just a script included in the main window?

Comment: This is a security feature. You can't change domain in the message. If you could set the domain name you could also trick people that the request is actually genuine even though it comes from some advertiser... That said, you'll have to deploy the script on `example.com` server to get the right domain string displayed.

Comment: @Touffy it's an external script included the way I show above. Another option is to include the script dynamically, where maybe I can also include a geolocation function, but that seems hacky. It's surprising to me that there's not a workaround for this. How do other geolocation widgets handle this?

Comment: I think you could do something like this..1) do geo in your domain scope (example.com) via something like `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(fn)` ,, then include dinamically another script and then simple use coords? .. OOOR do it like via your hidden iframe in your own widget (cdn.mywidget.com) that depends from some call wrom originated domain (example.com) and pass geo vars via iframe pars ?

Comment: On a non-technical aspect, make sure that it's written somewhere on the host website that the user's geolocation — should they agree to give it — is sent to your servers, with a link to your own privacy policy.

Comment: I was wrong. When including an external script that asks for geolocation, the browser will display the host domain, not the CDN domain. My CDN was caching results, so it did not expire old code, which is what was throwing me off. Long day, sorry for wasting your time, everybody.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't believe You.
You stated that Your script is included on example.com with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mywidget.com"></script>
```

If this is the case, then browser could only ask You about `example.com wants to use your computer's location`.

btw, who owns [example.com](http://example.com)?

Comment: That's good that you don't believe me. I explained my faulty reasoning in the last comment on the question.